# How to fill 'na' in a pandas df without changing it to a series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have the following case where I need to check if a column named 'status' is present in a pandas df. If yes, I check if another column named 'lsl' is present. If 'lsl' is also present, then I want to fill the NaN values in lsl with True(1) or False(0) based on the check if the value in 'status' == 5. If 'lsl' is not present, I want to create a new column 'lsl' with values True(1) or False(0) based on the check if the value in 'status' == 5.

Below is my code

```
def plot_lsl(df):
    print(type(df))
    if 'status' in df.columns:
        if 'lsl' in df.columns:
            df = df['lsl'].fillna(df['status'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore') == 5)
        else:
            df['lsl'] = (df['status'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore') == 5)
    print(type(df))
    df = df.dropna(subset=['lsl'])
    df['id'] = df['id'].str.upper()
    lsl_plot = px.scatter(data_frame = df, x=df.ts, y=df.lsl, color = "id")
```

I see that the first print(type(df)) returns a dataframe and the second one returns a series.
**Is there a method to retain df as a dataframe even after the mentioned process in the code?**

Because df was converted to a series, the subset argument in the dropna step is returning errors.
Any approach to improve my code is also highly welcome.

Comment: [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

Comment: Change `df = df['lsl'].fillna(df['status'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore') == 5)` to `df['lsl']= df['lsl'].fillna(df['status'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore') == 5)`.

`df['lsl'].fillna(df['status'].astype(int, errors = 'ignore') == 5)` is a series, and you're replacing `df` by that series in your current code.

Comment: @Seon Thanks a lot for pointing out and rectifying that silly mistake I made. OMG...I can't believe I made that mistake. 
Cheers
AJ